# If YITH Wishlist page is set to the WooCommerce my-account endpoint, the endpoints stop working all together. Any solution?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, e-commerce, endpoints, account

When using YITH to display the wishlist in the my-account endpoint of WooCommerce, the wishlist works fine, but the endpoints stop working. If we change the page to anything else other than the my-account endpoint, the problem goes away.

Comment: Your question is totally mess. Can you correct it?? What do you meant by works in my-account endpoint and  the problem goes away if changed to other page.  You probably meant the problem occurs in other page than my account page. I have used YITH wishlist plugin  and appears in my-account page. Are you trying to use some other page to show the wishlist??

Comment: If you go through the General Settings of the said plugin, there's an option called _Wishlist Page_ which by default points to the _Wishlist_ page. If I change that page to _My account_ then the WooCommerce endpoints, i.e. Dashboard, Orders, Downloads, Addresses, Account details, and Logout that are present in the My account page, stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Woocommerce->Status->Create default WooCommerce pages

Click button "Create pages" and they'll renew.
(Notice: before that, delete the Wishlist Page for the confidence.)